# Getting the key of the parent

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

```
{ JNC8IUYjH8WFmQPOKLiknoktlek1: 
    { buddy_user_id: 'MYYqI6iNd0MjDG6MgQ9OwXyChIG2',
     talk_room_id: '-LH2AphglHuyPR8N4wI-' }
}
```

I have this data return from this code:

```
.ref('/user_talk_rooms')
.onDelete(event => {
    console.log(event.data.previous.val())
})
```

What I want to is to get the value (JNC8IUYjH8WFmQPOKLiknoktlek1) but I don't know how to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Object.keys()`:

```js
var data = { JNC8IUYjH8WFmQPOKLiknoktlek1: 
    { buddy_user_id: 'MYYqI6iNd0MjDG6MgQ9OwXyChIG2',
     talk_room_id: '-LH2AphglHuyPR8N4wI-' }
};
var keys = Object.keys(data);
console.log(keys[0]);
```